# How to sum certain numbers in a python list?

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list that contains [date,data1,data2,data3...].
Now I need to sum all the data but not the date. How could I do that?
I hope I could get a new list that looks like [date,data1+data2+data3...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list slicing to get all of the original list except the first element. Then you can pass the resulting slice to `sum()`.

```
>>> original = ['date',11,222,3]
>>> summed = [original[0], sum(original[1:])]
>>> print(summed)
['date', 236]
```

Comment: That may be true, but OP specifically asked for a list.